# how can i animate the elements in the nav bar like this : https://riot.design/en/?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hey there im trying to do something like the effect on the nav bar here: 
https://riot.design/en/ 
this is the closest I got, pls help

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
  color: #31302B;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  margin: 25px;
  font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #31302B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 0 #31302B;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_sliding_bg">HELLOW</div>
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) then read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".div1").on("mouseover",function(){
  var $this=$(this).parent();
 $this.find(".div2").slideDown("fast");
 $this.find(".div1").slideUp("fast");
});

$(".div2").on("mouseleave",function(){
   var $this=$(this).parent();
    $this.find(".div1").slideDown("fast");
    $this.find(".div2").slideUp("fast");
});
```

```css
body{
background-color:#0C2663;
}
.element{
float:left;
width:65px;
margin:0 10px;

}
.element div{
width:60px;
margin-top:5px;
cursor:pointer;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;

}
.element div:last-child{
   background-color:#fff;
   color:#0C2663;
   display:none;
}
.element div:first-child{
   color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">
<div  class="div1">Home</div>
<div  class="div2">Home</div>
</div>
<div class="element">
<div  class="div1">About</div>
<div  class="div2">About</div>
</div>
<div class="element">
<div  class="div1">Portfolio</div>
<div  class="div2">Portfolio</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. The concept relies on the CSS `transform: translate` and `transform: rotate` properties to create the flipping cube effect.

Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #0B1F5C;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.flip-box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.face1,
.face2 {
  background: #0B1F5C;
  border: 1px solid #0B1F5C;
  height: 100px;
}

.face1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.face2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
  font-size: 25px;
  background: white;
  color: #0B1F5C;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="face1">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="face2">
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used chrome inspector on the link that you mentioned and created this for you. please ask questions that its answer could help other people too.

notice that beside the css3 transforms the trick is in

> .roll span:after

that the content of data-title attribute of the hovered element will be fetched and applied to the content property:

```
.roll span:after {
content: attr(data-title);
}

<span data-title="Home">Home</span>
```

```css
body{
  background-color:grey;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner {
 margin-top: 80px;
}

.navbar .nav {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar .nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.navbar .nav li:last-child a {
 padding-right: 0;
}

.lt-ie8 .navbar .nav li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.roll {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 200;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-perspective: 400px;
 -moz-perspective: 400px;
 -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
 -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.roll span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 2px;
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 18px;
}

a.roll:hover span {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
 -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

.roll span:after {
 content: attr(data-title);
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 1px;
 padding: 0 2px;
 color: #323C46;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
 -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="navbar">

<ul id="menu-primary-navigation-en" class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li class="active menu-home">
      <a href="https://riot.design/en/" class=" roll"><span data-title="Home">Home</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-about">
      <a href="https://riot.design/en/about/" class=" roll"><span data-title="About">About</span></a>
   </li>

  <li class="menu-portfolio">
    <a href="/en/portfolio/" class=" roll"><span data-title="Portfolio">Portfolio</span></a>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-contacts">
    <a href="https://riot.design/en/contacts/" class=" roll"><span data-title="Contacts">Contacts</span></a>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>

</body>
```